# How to do an infinite loop with Do While VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in excel with values and I would like that when the code run through all the cells it starts again, at the cell A2.

The code works smooth, I'm only having trouble to keep the loop going on.

```
Sub Loopall()
    i = 2
    
    
    Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    
        Range("A2").Select
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]").maximize
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "fbl5n"
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtDD_KUNNR-LOW").Text = Cells(i, 1)
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3
        
        i = i + 1
        
            
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        i = 2
    Else
        End If
        
        
        Loop
End sub
```

I've tried to place the if statement inside the loop, but then the code only reads the first cell. When placing the if outside the loop the code doesn't start the loop again when the cells are empty.

Comment: There are easier ways to crash the computer?

Comment: Are there easier ways to not help at all?

Comment: Just because you want and can do something doesn't mean you should. Stop and think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then` is restarting your loop when the cell is *not* blank, which seems like the opposite of what you'd want?

```vb
Sub Loopall()
    Const START_ROW as Long = 2
    i = START_ROW 
    
    Do 
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]").maximize
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "fbl5n"
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtDD_KUNNR-LOW").Text = Cells(i, 1)
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3
        i = i + 1
        If Len(Cells(i, 1)) = 0 Then i = START_ROW 
    Loop
End sub
```

Probably want to add in some way to escape the loop...

Comment: Appreciate your help, worked like a charm! I just didn't understand exactly what does the Len statement do. So when the loop ends it goes to cell 0, so if cell = 0 then we go to the starting row. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: `Len()` is Length, so it's just testing if the cell value is zero-length